# Combine two bitmap and save as jpg format in android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, jpeg

i have two bitmap in my project what i need is that i need to combine those two bit map and combine those bit map to a single image i will show my code

```
public class FotosurpriseActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Bitmap overlay;      
Paint pTouch;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android);
    Bitmap mBitmapover = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ss);
    overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ss).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);  
    c2 = new Canvas(overlay);

    pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
  //  pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.TARGET); 
    pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
    setContentView(new BitMapView(this, mBitmap,mBitmapover));
}

class BitMapView extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    Bitmap mBitmapover = null;

    public BitMapView(Context context, Bitmap bm, Bitmap bmover) {
    super(context);
    mBitmap = bm;
    mBitmapover = bmover;
    }
     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

         switch (ev.getAction()) {

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                 X = (int) ev.getX();
                 Y = (int) ev.getY();
                 invalidate();

                 break;
             }

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                     X = (int) ev.getX();
                     Y = (int) ev.getY();
                     invalidate();
                     break;

             }           

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                 break;

         }
         return true;
     }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // called when view is drawn
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    // The image will be scaled so it will fill the width, and the
    // height will preserve the imageâ€™s aspect ration
/*  double aspectRatio = ((double) mBitmap.getWidth()) / mBitmap.getHeight();
    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),(int) (this.getHeight() / aspectRatio));
    double aspectRatio2 = ((double) mBitmapover.getWidth()) / mBitmapover.getHeight();
    Rect dest2 = new Rect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),(int) (this.getHeight() / aspectRatio2));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, null, dest, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapover, null, dest2, paint);                    */

    //draw background
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it                          
    c2.drawBitmap(mBitmapover, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, pTouch);
    //draw the overlay over the background  
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

 }
```

how can i make this happen?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but what does compain mean?

Comment: i mean combine i have editted my question

Comment: I have find The solution To my answer from [This link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas)

Answer (score 0):

The onDraw function draws to the view. You don't actually need to do that at all. You can do this all in memory where the bitmaps reside. You draw the other bitmap on C2 as well. You don't have to draw anything to canvas in the onDraw() all that does is draw that to the screen.